# Pandas Dataframe exists outside of method. Why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets presume a I have a simple dataframe `df`
And a simple method that does something to the `dataframe`

```
def alterDF(df): 
    df1['new column'] = df['some column'] + x
    return df1
```

In the above method I modify an entire `column` with x and save it to a new variable name...inside the method! 
However, when I inspect my original dataframe (i.e. df) I see that it also has the new column added to it...

I am aware that the original `dataframe` I created exists outside of the method. But I would expect that any alterations that occur inside the method, should remain there, unless I save the changes via the `return` block in my method.

However, I know that I am wrong...the changes also applied within my method, also occur outside of my method. How can this be? Why is this so?

Comment: in python, (nearly) everything is pass-by-reference _unless_ you explicitly change the reference (by doing `name = new_reference`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you have a line like this

```
df1 = df # by doing this you copy the reference also
```

if you want to copy a dataframe use

```
df1 = df.copy()
```

instead

Comment: I would also add a link to [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html#mutability-and-copying-of-data) - it might help to understand the reason...

Comment: thanks. But I'm looking to make a copy of my original dataframe. Want to create a new dataframe, using an older dataframe as part of the input. I simply wanted to know if there would be a different way to do so, without updating the original dataframe.

Comment: @J.A.Cado that's exactly what df1 = df.copy()  does

Comment: My bad YOBA. Please excuse my ignorance.